# Input Boxes not aligning even after setting padding and margins

Tags: css

I am using following CSS code to align Input Boxes, but still nothing seems to work:

```
.EntryFormDiv.input
{
 padding-left: 100px;
 margin-left: 100px;
 left: 50px;
 width: 80px;
 text-transform: capitalize; 
}
```

What is the problem? I have added this class name on all the Input definitions.

Edited **

```
<div id="divBooksEntryForm" class="EntryFormDiv" runat="server">
    <label id="lblBookName" class="label" runat="server">Title of the Book: </label>
    <input id="inpBookName" class="input" runat="server" /><br />
    <label id="lblAuthor" class="label" runat="server">Author: </label>
    <input id="inpAuthor" class="input" runat="server" /><br />
    <label id="lblPublisher" class="label" runat="server">Publisher: </label>
    <input id="inpPublisher" class="input" runat="server" /><br />        
    <label id="lblCategory" class="label" runat="server">Category: </label>
    <input id="inpCategory" class="input" runat="server" /><br />
    <label id="lblSubCategory" class="label" runat="server">Sub-category: </label>
    <input id="inpSubCategory" class="input" runat="server" /><br />
    <label id="lblPurchaseDate" class="label" runat="server">Dt. of Purchase: </label><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Put a space between these:

```
.EntryFormDiv .input
```

What you wrote means: items that has both the classes `.EntryFormDiv` and `.input`. But with the space, it means items with class `.input` inside items with class `.EntryFormDiv`.

2 - `Left` can only be applied if `position` is other than `static`.

Comment: How to align the lefts of the input boxes?